# Wine : unable to write a file (MusicBee)

Tags: arch-linux, mount, wine

I've been trying to use MusicBee on my arch with wine, and I'm facing a weird problem I didn't expect.
When I try to create a Library (which is basically writing a file and creating folders as far as I know), I get the following error : [image: Error saying I can't access the folder where I wanted to create the Library]

It doesn't seem like wine limits access to mounted drives, so I have genuinely no idea what the problem is. Does anyone have any idea?

EDIT: I went to the path to check 3 things :

- I can write/create files there through other apps (file explorer for example)
- The problem doesn't come from having spaces in the name/folder (tried with underscores too)
- MusicBee/Wine actually manages to create the folder and a .ini file inside of it, so the problem comes after that, which is even weirder

Other people seem to encounter this problem on full Windows, so maybe there is a solution I haven't found yet. https://getmusicbee.com/forum/index.php?topic=28550.0

Comment: can you create a file in that directory "natively", for example in your file manager?

Comment: yes, and it seems MusicBee actually managed to create a folder and a file there, so I guess the problem is the part where it tries to access it? I'll update the question

Comment: "manage to create" *implies* accessing it. So, this might simply be a software bug in MusicBee?

Comment: other people managed to run MusicBee with wine so I don't know if it is a MusicBee error (in that case there is most likely a workaround). If I don't find anything I'll ask on their forum